# DataSource transport.destroy called +1 times for each successive delete (recalled for previously deleted items)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a `DataSource` in my code that support `destroy`. In order to delete object from the it, i directly call `remove`, i.e.

```
myDataSource.remove(discardedData);
```

I get a behavior similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403543/kendo-datasource-transport-destroy-with-function-got-called-too-much). However, unlike the linked thread, my `destroy` is not set to a function, so the solution does not help me.

My DataSource (i included all of it in case some of my configuration is to blame):

```
       var QueueMessages = {
        type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: BASE_URL + "api/QueueMessages/GetMessagesHeaders",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authService.getAuth());
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: BASE_URL + "api/QueueMessages/deleteMessage",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "DELETE",
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authService.getAuth());
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    profileName: { type: "string" },
                    queueType: { type: "string" },
                    acceptedAt: { type: "date" },
                    processedAt: { type: "date" },
                    BodyExcerpt: { type: "string" }
                }
            },
            total: "total",
            data: "data",
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //throw user back to login page
            if (e.errorThrown === "Unauthorized")
                $rootScope.$apply($location.path('/'));
        },
        requestStart: function () {
        },
        requestEnd: function () {
        },
        pageSize: 50,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverGrouping: true,
        serverAggregates: true
    };
```

I cant find any clues as to why this is happening.

Comment: The problem is likely to be the same than in the link that you refer: the result of executing a destroy is not informing that it has finished correctly. Your service should return an appropriate result in order to inform `destroy` that it has been actually removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [OnaBai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802671/onabai) I found the problem.

consulting [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5), i my changed the http `DELETE` response from 200 `OK` to 204 `no content`.